# Pandas Dataframe - Sum values for a specific date then divide by the count of that date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several dates, and several values for each date, I'm trying to sum the values of each date then divide by the number of records for that same date.

Example:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-16 | 1 |
| 2022-09-16 | 2 |
| 2022-09-16 | 3 |
| 2022-09-15 | 6 |
| 2022-09-15 | 2 |
| 2022-09-15 | 2 |
| 2022-09-14 | 7 |

The expected result for this would be a new dataframe containing the sum of the values for the date divided by the count of values for each date:
Eg:

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-16 | 2 |
| 2022-09-15 | 3.3333 |
| 2022-09-14 | 7 |

2022-09-16 would be:
`(1+2+3)/3`

My current code for this function is the following so far:

```py
  dfyieldd = pd.read_sql_query(getmacrofactorvalues, conn)
            dfyieldd.to_csv('dfyieldd_raw.csv')
            

            resultseries = pd.Series(data=dfyieldd['rawvalue'])
            resultzscored = zscoreoutliers(resultseries)
        
            dfyieldd['value'] = resultzscored
            dfyieldd.to_csv('dfyieldd_zcored.csv')

            
            dfyieldd.set_index('datadate')
            dfyieldd.index=pd.to_datetime(dfyieldd.index)
```

My question is if there is any way to do this without having to use foreach. I could achieve it by looping through the dates, but it doesn't feel it's the proper way to deal with it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using `groups = df.groupby('date')`  and then `groups['value'].mean()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) to aggregate then [**`pandas.Series.div`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html?highlight=div#pandas.Series.div) to divide cols.

Try this :

```
out = (
        dfyieldd.groupby('date')['value'].agg(['sum','count'])
                .assign(value=lambda x: x.pop('sum').div(x.pop('count')))
                .reset_index()
      )
```

Or simply by using [**`pandas.Series.mean`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html?highlight=mean#pandas.Series.mean) :

```
out = dfyieldd.groupby('date', as_index=False)['value'].mean()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

         date     value
0  2022-09-14  7.000000
1  2022-09-15  3.333333
2  2022-09-16  2.000000
```